# Mir 100 pause and continue via rest api

Tags: python-3.x, rest, robotics

I've been working with mir 100 and using Python to make rest API requests and now I'm trying to pause and unpause the robot via rest API, I'm not working in mir fleet, just one robot, I try to use the action post to make the request to pause the robot via Postman to make some tests, the robot status code was 201 (success) but the robot doesn't stops, someone know how I should make the request correctly?

This is the JSON that I am using:

```
{
"allowed_methods":null,
  "descriptions": [
    null
  ],
  "help": "string",
  "parameters": [
    "pause"
  ],
  "mission_group_id": "2a4c6731-1fd4-11ee-b4c4-94c691a733c6",
  "name": "pause",
  "action_type": "pause",
  "description": "string"
}
```

And this is the request url: http://ip/api/v2.0.0/actions/pause

Answer (score 0):

I've also been trying to play/pause the mission via RestAPI.

I'm unable to pause the robot from /actions/pause API call.

I can do it from the Put call to /status. The API documentation lets you "try it out" and outlines the parameters for the body to send. You can omit whatever you don't need. I determined the values by playing/pausing the robot and execute the get/status call from the robot's API documentation webpage. Get to it via the robot interface at help/API documentation, then log in and launch as the user for the calls.

The body parameters are:

```
{
 "map_id": "string",
  "mode_id": 0,
  "state_id": 0,
  "web_session_id": "string",
  "position": {},
  "serial_number": "string",
  "name": "string",
  "answer": "string",
  "guid": "string",
  "datetime": "2023-10-05T17:12:08.182Z",
  "clear_error": true
}
```

You can just send the state id, no comma at the end:

```
{
  "state_id": 0
}
```

Play is state 3 and pause is 4.